# Page cutting off half way when in full screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Trying to create a login page for my capstone project and for osme reason the form I created isnt taking up the fullscreen

Made a form for a login page with columns styled in Bootstrap, expected it to fill up the screen but for some reason just takes up about half with the other half being white.

```css
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}



.main-head{
    height: 150px;
    background: #FFF;
   
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 20px;
}


.main {
    padding: 0px 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    .login-form{
        margin-top: 10%;
    }

    .register-form{
        margin-top: 10%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
    .main{
        margin-left: 40%; 
    }

    .sidenav{
        width: 40%;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    .login-form{
        margin-top: 80%;
    }

    .register-form{
        margin-top: 20%;
    }
}


.login-main-text{
    margin-top: 20%;
    padding: 60px;
    color: #fff;
}

.login-main-text h2{
    font-weight: 300;
}

.btn-black{
    background-color: #000 !important;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="sitestyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>Excell Visualizer</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div class="sidenav">
    <div class="login-main-text">
        <h2>Chartcel <br> Login Page </h2>
        <p>Login or register from here to upload your desired spreadsheet.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <div class="login-form">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Username </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-black">Login</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary"> Register</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Screenshot of problem:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wYtM.png)

Answer (score 1):

You're having this issue because the .sidenav class has a width of 40%
so the other 60% is just whitespace.

just set the width of .sidenav to 100% and remove the margin-left: 40% property from the .main class.

```
.main {
  padding: 0px 10px;
  width: 100%; /* Add this here */
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.main-head {
    height: 150px;
    background: #FFF;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
}

.main {
    padding: 0px 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {
        padding-top: 15px;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    .login-form {
        margin-top: 10%;
    }

    .register-form {
        margin-top: 10%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .sidenav {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    .login-form {
        margin-top: 80%;
    }

    .register-form {
        margin-top: 20%;
    }
}

.login-main-text {
    margin-top: 20%;
    padding: 60px;
    color: #fff;
}

.login-main-text h2 {
    font-weight: 300;
}

.btn-black {
    background-color: #000 !important;
    color: #fff;
}

.login-form {
  margin-top: 20%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.btn {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="sitestyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <title>Excell Visualizer</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div class="sidenav">
    <div class="login-main-text">
        <h2>Chartcel <br> Login Page </h2>
        <p>Login or register from here to upload your desired spreadsheet.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <div class="login-form">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Username </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-black">Login</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary"> Register</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

I also noticed when I did this that your elements aren't centering properly so I've added the following CSS rules to fix this.

```
.login-form {
  margin-top: 20%;
  padding: 20px;
}

.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.btn {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You really need to edit your question to turn your code into a snippet which demonstrates the problem. I have turned your code into a snippet here in my answer, but I can't see the problem.

```css
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}



.main-head{
    height: 150px;
    background: #FFF;
   
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding-top: 20px;
}


.main {
    padding: 0px 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
    .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
}

@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    .login-form{
        margin-top: 10%;
    }

    .register-form{
        margin-top: 10%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
    .main{
        margin-left: 40%; 
    }

    .sidenav{
        width: 40%;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    .login-form{
        margin-top: 80%;
    }

    .register-form{
        margin-top: 20%;
    }
}


.login-main-text{
    margin-top: 20%;
    padding: 60px;
    color: #fff;
}

.login-main-text h2{
    font-weight: 300;
}

.btn-black{
    background-color: #000 !important;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="sidenav">
    <div class="login-main-text">
        <h2>Chartcel <br> Login Page </h2>
        <p>Login or register from here to upload your desired spreadsheet.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <div class="login-form">
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Username </label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Password</label>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-black">Login</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary"> Register</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, run the code and put it in full screen